# Change x509 certificate attributes (i.e. Organization) when signing

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509, pki, ca

I've built an internal signing CA using OpenSSL.

My signing policy requires certain attributes to MATCH, including organizationName

```
[ match_pol ]
organizationName        = supplied  # Must match 'Company ABC'
organizationalUnitName  = optional  # Included if present
commonName              = supplied  # Must be present
countryName             = supplied  # Must be present
```

Some of the CSR's I'm being given to sign from people don't have the correct organizationName (typo's, etc)

Am I able to modify the OrganizationName (or other attributes) before returning the signed certificate so it matches the name I want, and without having to reject and ask for a new CSR from the user?

I know from personal experience the CSRs I upload to DigiCert can contain any value and the returned signed certificate will have the correct EV/OV name that has been approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `ca` tool (`openssl ca`) to operate your CA then you can use the `-subj` option to override the Subject within the request:

> **-subj arg**
> supersedes subject name given in the request. The arg must be formatted as /type0=value0/type1=value1/type2=..., characters may be escaped by \ (backslash), no spaces are skipped.

Combined the with the following option(s) to configure the extensions (including Subject Alternate Name), you should be able to modify all the attributes and extensions:

> **-extensions section**
> the section of the configuration file containing certificate extensions to be added when a certificate is issued (defaults to x509_extensions unless the -extfile option is used). If no extension section is present then, a V1 certificate is created. If the extension section is present (even if it is empty), then a V3 certificate is created. See the x509v3_config(5) manual page for details of the extension section format.

and, possibly:

> **-extfile file**
> an additional configuration file to read certificate extensions from (using the default section unless the -extensions option is also used).

Comment: OMG I must have read the man pages a hundred times but never digested the -subj arg... thank you